Save 16-bit PGM Image with Python PIL?
I am attempting to convert an image in PNG format to a 16-bit PGM format and save it using Python's PIL library. I'm using Python 3.12.4 in all examples shown.

Using the following test.png image:

Attempting a simple script like this with the Image.save function:
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("test.png")
image.save("test.pgm")

Can save resave the image as PGM, however it's always saved as an 8-bit image, as shown by GIMP:


Attempting to specify the amount of pixel bits via the optional bits argument as such:
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("test.png")
image.save("test.pgm", bits = 16)

Also results in an 8-bit PGM image being saved.

Attempting to manually create a numpy array of the np.uint16 type & then creating an image from it using the Image.fromarray function as such:
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

image = Image.open("test.png")
imageData = np.array(image.getdata(), dtype = np.uint16)
newImage = Image.fromarray(imageData)
newImage.save("test.pgm", bits = 16)

Results in:
OSError: cannot write mode I;16 as PPM

I also noticed that this appears to break the image, as saving with np.uint32 saves a blank image with a very narrow horizontal size and a very large vertical size.

What is the proper way to save 16-bit PGM images using the Python PIL library?

According to the documentation, PIL reads and writes PGM images in the 1, L, I and RGB modes. Have you tried explicitly opening your input file / saving your output file in L mode, or luminance/grayscale?

Also, according to various specifications I've read online, some say PGM supports up to 16-bit grayscale values, while others say it only supports 8-bit. Double check that what you're trying to do is even possible.

@PaulM. thanks for your replies; Yes, I have tried explictly opening the image in the RGB mode, with convert("RGB"), made no difference. The PNG images I'm working with are all RGB, without alpha already. And yes, PGM does support 16-bit grayscale. I have been working with images that are 16-bit PGM, I can verify that in GIMP it says 16-bit gamma integer for those images. So I know for sure that PGM supports 16-bit, just unsure of how to export such images using PIL or any other Python libraries.

You've gone very quiet since I posted an answer... how did you get on with it?

Use np.uint32 which results in an I mode PIL Image rather than I;16 mode. Like this:
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Create numpy array to use as image
a = np.arange(0,65536,100, np.uint32)

# Make numpy array into PIL Image
im = Image.fromarray(a)
im.save('result.pgm')

# DEBUG/clarification
print(im)

Prints:
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=I size=1x656 at 0x13112EA50>

Check result
exiftool result.pgm

File Name                       : result.pgm
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 1327 bytes
File Modification Date/Time     : 2024:07:11 23:02:29+01:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2024:07:11 23:02:29+01:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2024:07:11 23:02:33+01:00
File Permissions                : -rw-r--r--
File Type                       : PGM
File Type Extension             : pgm
MIME Type                       : image/x-portable-graymap
Image Width                     : 1
Image Height                    : 656
Max Val                         : 65535   <--- This proves it is 16-bit
Image Size                      : 1x656
Megapixels                      : 0.000656


So why would it work with np.uint32 but not with np.uint16?

@MarkRansom Based on my observation uint16 input to fromarray produces images with mode "I;16", whereas uint32 makes just "I". And then there's this bit: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/main/src/PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py#L336 which only seems to handle that latter case. Bug or an oversight? Hard to say...

@MarkRansom Exactly as per Dan's comment.

How are you getting a Max Val of 65535 when you created it with a range that ends at 65500?  That's a bit suspicious.

@MarkRansom The NetPBM spec calls for a MAXVAL of 255 for 8-bit images and a MAXVAL of 65535 for 16-bit images. It isn't a value that has to actually be present in an image, just the maximum value it could contain.

Thanks for that, it's been so long since I used PGM that I forgot.  And there's an alternate way to save the image if you want to keep it as uint16: im.convert('I').save('result.pgm').

Well, it appears it's possible to do with opencv:
import cv2
import numpy as np

img8 = cv2.imread("test.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img16 = ((img8 / 256) * 65536).astype("uint16")
cv2.imwrite("test.pgm", img16)

Haven't been able to find a way with PIL though yet..
